# How to solve error while implementing Sign in with Google Plus and Facebook in an activity?

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception, google-plus

Here, I'm integrating Sign in with Facebook and G+ in my project which is working fine if I integrate to each in individual activities but if I integrate to both of them in the same activity I start getting an error in the code of G+. For more I'm going to paste my code and error. My `LoginActivity` where I'm integrating to both of them together is

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
// Your Facebook APP ID
private static String APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Replace with your App
                                                    // ID
LinearLayout ll;
// Strings of Facebook
String fb_mUserId = "", fb_mUserToken = "", fb_mUserName = "",
        fb_mUserEmail = "", fb_verified_value = "", fb_Task_message;
boolean fb_verified, google_verified;
// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
EditText edittext_username, edittext_password;
Button Btn_login, Btn_register;
TextView Text_univesity, errorMsg, tv_forget_password;
LinearLayout ll_google, ll_fb;
static String Username, password, name, Twilio_Id = "",
        name_candidate = "", phone_no = "", email_candidate = "",
        country = "", mobile_verification = "", fb_id = "";
ImageView im;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
int id, Mode = 0, fb_clicked = 0, google_clicked = 0;
static int user_ids;
String IMEI_number;
GPSTracker gps;
static double latitude = 0.00, longitude = 0.00;
Context context;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
// Logcat tag
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
// Profile pic image size in pixels
// private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
/**
 * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
 * from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;
private boolean mSignInClicked;
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
// Strings of Google Plus
String google_email="", google_id="", google_name="", google_verified_value="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    IMEI_number = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);


    if (Mode == 3) {
        if (login_details.contains("name")) {
            name = login_details.getString("name", "");
            Intercom.client().registerIdentifiedUser(
                    new Registration().withUserId(name));
        } else {
            Intercom.client().registerIdentifiedUser(
                    new Registration().withUserId("123456"));
        }
        // We're logged in, we can register the user with Intercom
        // Carry on as normal
        Intent mode = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuItems.class);
        startActivity(mode);
        finish();
    } else {
        edittext_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_login_password);
        Btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        Btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_register);
        ll_fb = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_fb);
        ll_google = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_google);
        tv_forget_password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_login_forget_password);
        Btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        Btn_register.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll_fb.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll_google.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_forget_password.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initializing google plus api client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).build();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_login:
   // Direct Login Process
        break;
    case R.id.btn_login_register:
        // Direct register process
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.login_fb:
        fb_clicked++;
        loginToFacebook();
        getProfileInformation();
        if (!fb_mUserEmail.equals("")) {
            if (fb_verified == true) {
                fb_verified_value = "1";
            } else {
                fb_verified_value = "0";
            }
            new FacebookAsynTask().execute();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.login_google:
        google_clicked++;
        signInWithGplus();
    //  getGoogleProfileInformation();
        if (!google_email.equals("")) {
            if (google_verified == true) {
                google_verified_value = "1";
            } else {
                google_verified_value = "0";
            }
            new GoogleAsynTask().execute();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.tv_login_forget_password:
        break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/** LOGIN TO FACEBOOK */
public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "FIRST CASE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        getProfileInformation();
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_actions" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "SECOND CASE",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getProfileInformation();

                        // Making Login button invisible

                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error
                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors
                    }

                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (fb_clicked != 0) {
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb_clicked = 0;
    }
    else if (google_clicked != 0) {

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
        google_clicked = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
 * */
public void getProfileInformation() {
    try {

        JSONObject profile = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        Log.e("Profile", "" + profile);
        fb_mUserId = profile.getString("id");
        fb_verified = profile.getBoolean("verified");
        fb_mUserToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
        fb_mUserName = profile.getString("name");
        fb_mUserEmail = profile.getString("email");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Log.e("FaceBook_Profile", "" + fb_mUserId + "\n"
                        + fb_mUserToken + "\n" + fb_mUserName + "\n"
                        + fb_mUserEmail);
            }
        });

    } catch (FacebookError e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/** AsyncTask of Direct Login */


class FacebookAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

}

/** GOOGLE's CODE STARTS */
/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get user's information
    getGoogleProfileInformation();

    // Update the UI after signin
    // updateUI(true);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    // updateUI(false);
}

/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getGoogleProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            google_name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            google_id = currentPerson.getId();
            google_verified = currentPerson.isVerified();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            google_email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + google_name + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + google_email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class GoogleAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
}
```

Here, I get problem in this method of `NullPointerException`.

```
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

My `LogCat` shows like this:

```
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.u18.enroll.LoginActivity.resolveSignInError(LoginActivity.java:752)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.u18.enroll.LoginActivity.signInWithGplus(LoginActivity.java:744)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.u18.enroll.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:236)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17431)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-08 10:42:40.844: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 10:42:43.446: E/NativeCrypto(11981): ssl=0x5f72edf0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5eaafaa0 arg=0x0
07-08 10:42:43.447: E/NativeCrypto(11981): ssl=0x5f72edf0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

It shows error in `236` line where I'm calling `signInWithGplus()` method

If anybody has solve this problem then help me and give me a right way.

Thanks.

Comment: where is your error log?

Comment: In the first line of `resolveSignInError` method `if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {`

Comment: @Sree Logcat is added now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22809017

Comment: This isn't solution for me because it works fine if I integrate Google Plus in an another class.

Comment: i think this is happening in second time of login is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82669/discussion-between-anshul-tyagi-and-sree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, i solved this problem with the help of `Sree` by just one condition which is

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        getProfileInformation();
    } else {
        signInWithGplus();
        getProfileInformation();
    } 
}
```